# Field Service - How to get record id inside visual flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, parameters, fieldservice

Iv'e created a flow that is embedded inside fsl app.
Inside the flow App Extension I set it to run only on WorkOrder object.
I need to use the record id inside my flow but i'm not able to get it.

I read the following:

"When the Field Service Lightning mobile app launches into a flow, it passes the following input parameters:
– Id: The record ID of the record that the workflow is launched from.
– ParentId: The record ID of the parent record that the workflow is launched from. For example, if a workflow is launched
from a service appointment, this will be the ID of the parent work order or work order line item.
– UserId: The ID of the current user."

I tried to create a variable inside my flow with the name Id (type - Text, input/output), but still, this is not working.

Hope someone can help me figuring this out ..

It's important to say that i'm using fsl configuration that are a bit different than the usual settings ..

Thanks !

Comment: I'm working on this, too - any progress?

Comment: Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create ja Text Variable called "Id" that is availavle for Input.
[image]

Step two is, get the data that you want

[image]

The Varibale "Id" is the ID from the scoped Object in the Field Service Mobile Settings.

[image]

PS: FSL will work offline to, the App priming all records form the Service Appointment in this Case.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. Id helps instead of recordId

Comment: @TruptiRajput Welcome to SFSE - no need for 'thanks' posts, just upvote the answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

"Id" worked for me not "recordId" to fetch current record for Mobile service flow

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score -2):

Create a variable called "recordId" exactly, not "Id".